# Converting a HaXml Document to a Content

Tags: xml-parsing, haskell

I am looking for a HaXml library function to convert a `Text.XML.HaXml.Types.Document` to a `Text.XML.HaXml.Types.Content`.

In the book **Real World Haskell**, the following function is provided:

```
getContent :: Document -> Content
getContent (Document _ _ e _) = CElem e
```

I believe that this should be changed to

```
getContent :: Document -> Content
getContent (Document _ _ e _) = CElem e undefined
```

I am surprised that I cannot find anything similar in the HaXml packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you want is [`docContent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaXml/1.23.3/doc/html/Text-XML-HaXml-Util.html#v%3adocContent),

```
docContent :: i -> Document i -> Content i
```

The haddock says

> Get the main element of the document so that you can apply `CFilters` directly. `i` is typically `(posInNewCxt filename Nothing)`

its implementation is more or less the expected,

```
docContent i (Document _ _ e _) = CElem e i
```

The mismatch between the code of RWH and now is because when RWH was written, the `HaXml` version was 1.13.*, when the types `Document` and `Content` were not yet parametrized.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what I need. Thanks.